# mongo import with special characters in string through csv using java

Tags: java, mongodb, csv-import

I am trying to import the csv file to mongodb using java in that for one field called question may  contain  the special characters in the string .
After importing the csv in db it is replacing the **special characters** with the 
**Question mark** how to over come  it please help me with this .
currently i am using the below mentioned implementation for importing

> csv input is :    If ∠A, ∠B and ∠C of ΔABC are equal, then triangle is .
>   *Db output is :* "question" : "If **?A, ?B and ?C of ?ABC** are equal,
>   then triangle is"   Here angle symbol is replacing with question mark.
>   it should not happen

```
 String filesavedpath="D://nithin" + "/"+csvfilename;

   String command = "mongoimport" + " --db dbname --collection collectionname" +
             "-f quizname,question,option_1,option_2,option_3,option_4,answer --type csv --file " + filesavedpath;
```

Thanks in advance
sunil

Comment: You need to consider the encoding, otherwise the unicode replacement character (the question mark) start to appear. I.e. reading data as UTF-8, when it's actually something like ISO-8859-1 will botch special characters.

Comment: Special characters like what exactly? You need to be more specific and also certain about "replacing". `mongoimport` will work happily with UTF-8 Data. It may well be that your "console/terminal" just does not display these characters properly.

Comment: Please do not post links to images of data, copy/paste a representative sample of the _INPUT_ data, ***including the special characters that are getting munged*** into your post.  Format as `CODE`.

Comment: I call bunk on this. I just put your special characters into a file and imported them without a problem. As stated, it's more likely that what you are using to view the data is either incapable of presenting the encoding or the actual file was saved with the incorrect encoding. You should be using UTF-8, for which those characters displayed are valid.

Answer (score 3):

1. Step1: Save Excel sheet myFile.xlsx as myFile.csv file using
   MS-Excel file menu
2. Step2: Open the saved CSV file using Notepad as and save as myFile.csv but change the encoding to UTF-8 while saving and overwrite the existing CSV file.

[Save As screenshot on notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld3VE.png)
[MongoDB content after loading data using mongoimport from csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvfJ0.png)

Answer (score -1):

I have worked on your issue to upload csv to db.I had found one solution for your problem.You have to use Libre office and open file as Character set(UTF-8) and save as .csv